# Why I do not see the file path in a simple falco rule output concerning the cat command?

Tags: falco

Here is my rule:

```
- rule: My test rule
  desc: Alert when cat is executed
  condition: spawned_process and proc.name = cat
  output: TEST_RULE_ALERT (command=%proc.cmdline pid=%proc.pid file=%fd.name user=%user.name user_loginuid=%user.loginuid container_id=%container.id image=%container.image.repository)
  priority: notice
```

Here is the output when running `cat /tmp/xyz`:

```
Jun 03 14:31:56 cks-worker falco[21118]: 14:31:57.851590469: Notice TEST_RULE_ALERT (command=cat /tmp/xyz pid=59166 file=<NA> user=mark user_loginuid=1000 container_id=host image=<NA>)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spawned_process` macro triggers the alert when you execute the `cat` command. However, the file isn't opened right at its execution but when the control has passed to the code of the `cat` command. In other words, you'd need to observe the event of opening a file, not executing the command.

Hence, you should observe syscalls like `open`, `openat`, and `openat2`, which are used to open files. Using the `open_read` macro would do that for you.